# Can a UDK 3D interface be used to render the output of all the GPL text dungeon rpg games?

Tags: gpl-3, proprietary-code

Can a UDK (unreal development kit, unreal engine) 3D interface be used to render the output of all the GPL text dungeon rpg games?

So, lets say i implement a 3D AAA interface using UDK5 top quality.
Now, it will read the text output of GPL games where the hero is a "@" and orcs are "o".
Then based on the previous turn, that 3D interface will rotate all 3D models properly (it will guess to where the models should be looking at, w/o talking to the gpl game).
The sfx and music could still play from the 2D text game or not.
The 3D interface would do a lot of guess work and would have a set of config files specific for each 2D text dungeon turn based game.
Its main view is isometric, but being 3d you could even go 1st person.

Does UDK5 or newer allow this kind of interaction with open source restrictive licenses like GPL?

Comment: Please assume that readers don't know what "UDK" is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you propose that this "UDK 3D interface" get the 2D output from the GPL game?  Camera pointed at the screen?  Or something a bit more tightly coupled with the GPL program?

Comment: @MadHatter the output goes to a plaint text terminal. UDK will monitor all text updates on the terminal and update the 3d scene accordingly. (i added udk definition).

Comment: @Community are you a bot or someone really asking? As your request is already detailed. If you need clarifications, please be specific.

Comment: Is this a one-way process, or is there a feedback loop (ie, is someone playing this 3D-rendered game but their inputs are being fed back to the GPL 2D game)?

Comment: Would you be able to have the interface working with a closed-source game? Or would you need access to the game's sources in order to get a proper 3D rendering? If you don't need the sources in any way, your interface is probably independent copyright wise and the copyright license on the game is irrelevant.

Comment: @MadHatter no, the input goes directly to the text dungeon. UDK 3D only renders the captured text output, and plays sfx and music also based on descriptibe hints it gets from the game log. On UDK interface you only config how it will interpret the 2D text game output. So the input focus goes directly to the text dungeon game. Unreal engine will be like a ontop windows without focus.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau it will only interpret the text output based on a cfg. The text dungeon app will never know unreal engine was doing anything. We could even edit a text file manually, like if we are playing a table top rpg online with friends like dungeons and drangons, and that text file would be rendered in 3D.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe and clarified in the comments, this 3D viewer is not tied to one particular game. It can be used with games with various licenses and even a transcript of table-top RPG games.

That means that copyright wise, your 3D viewer is not a derived work of any of the games you view with it. The output from the game is just data that the 3D viewer reads in and uses to render a 3D scenery.

If two works are copyright wise unrelated, then their respective copyright licenses also don't affect each other. This means that you don't need to care about the game's copyright license in choosing the copyright license of your 3D viewer. Even a strong copyleft license, like the GPL, on the game does not affect your choices for the license of the 3D viewer.